# Android Constraint Layout margins change then revert back

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, layoutmargins

After setting all four layout constraints, I attempt to set the margins. The margins morph to the desired UI (photo #2), but then immediately revert back to the original form (photo #1). This effectively nullifies the changes set to the margins. Photo #3 is a more apparent example of the problem. Does anyone know what is wrong?

## 1

[UI before and after adding margin (there is no change)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2OG9.png)

## 2

[desired UI (effect the margin should have)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRMCu.png)

## 3

[strange UI result (separate from 1 & 2, is an example of the problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtNfK.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
tools:context=".SettingsActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/settingsTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Settings"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/turnSettingSpinner"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:entries="@array/turn_settings"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/settingsTextView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Show me expected UI do you want?

Comment: photo #2 is desired UI, photo #1 is the result regardless of margin constraint

Answer (score 0):

layout_margin was set to 8dp, so every change I made to the four specified margins (i.e. layout_marginTop, layout_marginLeft, etc.) would not "stick" and would instead revert back to the specified default value of 8dp.